# Matplotlibrc needs to be updated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, matplotlib

So I wiped Python 3.6 some weeks ago and seem to have incorrectly reinstalled matplotlib etc because I've been getting a bunch of errors for different things.

I'm trying to run a script that displays a number of images side by side using subplot. Tried it from the command line, worked fine. But when I write it all up in a script and try to run it (I have about 24 images) I get the following error:

> You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from
>   http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/matplotlibrc.template
>   or from the matplotlib source distribution Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "./merge_pics.py", line 8, in 
>       fig=plt.figure()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 527, in
>   figure
>       **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
>   line 84, in new_figure_manager
>       return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
>   line 101, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
>       icon_img = Tk.PhotoImage(file=icon_fname)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3370, in **init**
>       Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3324, in **init**
>       self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
>   _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/images/matplotlib.gif": no such file
>   or directory

When I click on the link I can't tell where I'm supposed to get the updated matplotlibrc file.

I have tried wget http://github.... but still get the same error

Matplotlib is definitely installed because trying to plot simple things is working so I can't figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Such an error would not happen if matplotlib is correctly installed. Now it's very hard to know what went wrong with your installation. I guess the aim would be to remove matplotlib completely and do a clean reinstall.

Comment: How would one go about removing matplotlib?

Answer (score 3):

I have tried and fixed this error successfully.
Firstly, you should uninstall matplotlib by

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
```

Then, you install it again by

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Feel free to ask more.