# jupyter notebook shows error message for matplotlib Bad key "text.kerning_factor"

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Bad key "text.kerning_factor" on line 4 in
/home/samyak/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/_classic_test_patch.mplstyle.
You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.1.3/matplotlibrc.template
or from the matplotlib source distribution

Comment: Please share the contents of the environment.

Answer (score 16):

It seems to be the case that one of style config files is for matplotlib 3.1 despite that 3.2 is installed.

1. Go to `/home/samyak/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/`
2. open `_classic_test_patch.mplstyle` and comment out the line of `text.kerning_factor:6`

It worked for me.

Comment: This also solved my problem. I made the mistake of upgrading matplotlib to 3.2.1 using pip and now it won't uninstall so i may be stuck with this version until a new one comes out...

Comment: i had a similar problem but after solving as you said the remainder of the error message insisted.

can anyone think how the error shown above can be related to this error:
      from ._cwt import *
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_zoo\lib\site-packages\pywt\_cwt.py", line 17, in <module>
    next_fast_len = fftmodule.next_fast_len
AttributeError: module 'scipy.fft' has no attribute 'next_fast_len'
python-BaseException
   next_fast_len = fftmodule.next_fast_len
AttributeError: module 'scipy.fft' has no attribute 'next_fast_len'
?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I solved it by upgrading Matplotlib using the code:

```
conda upgrade matplotlib
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling also works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63760671/300745

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue today (using version 3.2.1).

**My solution**: Reinstall matplotlib :)

Comment: one extra step if the issue persist is to delete any folder in site-packages with name matplotlib. That'll clear everything and reinstall will do everything from scratch and that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed the version of `matplotlib` that `print(matplotlib.__version__)` returned was different from the version that `pip show matplotlib` showed! When I checked the folder `./Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages` I noticed there were two versions of `matplotlib` (and a few other packages, too). For some reason when I upgraded `matplotlib` (and other packages), the old versions were not uninstalled. I used

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
```

*twice* to remove both versions, then installed matplotlib again. This solved the problem.

Comment: This was my problem.  I somehow had 2 versions of matplotlib installed.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same problem. Reinstalling matplotlib didn't work for me. I downgraded matplotlib to version 2 using:

conda install matplotlib=2

It worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For me it sufficed to install/upgrade the current version of matplotlib from conda-forge instead of the default channel (no previous uninstall necessary):

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `matplotlib` from the active environment.
2. Go to './Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages' and manually delete all the `matplotlib` folders you see there. Make sure you are in the same environment if you have more than one.
3. Re-install 'matplotlib' using `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib`.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

i uninstalled matplotlib from my active environment and then reinstalled using

conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib

that did the trick!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).